# Detect a specific ajax transaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a mechanism where I run an ajax transaction to use long polling technique, so that request will keep open for a while. But I have another mechanism where every time that the page make a load or another ajax transaction with

```
   ajaxStart ()
```

event I draw an loading icon, and when the ajax transaction finish detected with the event

```
   ajaxComplete()
```

I hide that icon with.

My question is, is there any way to know which ajaxTransaction I´m getting on my ajaxStart and ajaxComplete to do not nothing in case is the long polling ajax transaction?.

Regards.

Comment: @MalaKa - Thanks for the tag correction. A suggestion: Since it's now been fixed, you and Paul could remove your comments to reduce clutter in the page - and then I'll remove this comment too. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `global: false` in your `$.ajax()` call that does the long polling:

```
$.ajax({
    global: false,
    // the rest of your parameters
});
```

That will prevent this `$.ajax()` call from firing any of the global ajax events: `ajaxStart`, `ajaxStop`, `ajaxSend`, `ajaxSuccess`, `ajaxError`, and `ajaxComplete`. Other `$.ajax()` calls in your code will still fire these events as usual, unless you've disabled them globally with `$.ajaxSetup({global:false})`.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/7m8r0j6L/) that demonstrates this.

Documentation pages:

[`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/)

[Global Ajax Event Handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) (This page is incomplete; it fails to mention that you can use `global: false` on an individual `$.ajax()` call.)